# UDP connection between 2 ios device

Tags: ios, udp

I am currently using **GCDAsyncUdpSocket** to build a app that can communicate with UDP protocol.

I am testing whether the connection work with this iPhone app "**UDP_Test**" >> [App link](http://itunes.apple.com/kz/app/udp-test/id499559043?mt=8)

When I send msg from my iOS simulator, the message does appear received on my iPhone "UDP_Test" app. However, when I download my project to the other iPhone and setup the connection with the iPhone that has "UDP_Test" app, the communication does not work.

Then I tried using "UDP_Test" for the two iPhone to communicate, it does not work as well. Same goes to iPad and iPhone. Is there a restriction for both iOS device to communicate with UDP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way. We have to go to Network setting and choose your network. Then go to "HTTP Proxy" and choose "Manual" then enter the port that your device going to listen to, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your two devices needed to be on the same subnet of the WiFi network.

Comment: my both devices are connected to the same wifi